# Signed Applet security warning on Java Update

Tags: java, security, applet, signed-applet

I have created a jar and added trusted security certificate to it. This works good till Java 7 Update 21+ pops up.

From the update I see the warning message "The application contains both signed and unsigned code".

I have seen so many queries on the same problem posted here but my bad that nothing helped me.

After some random search I have seen the link,
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html
and
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8016771

Explains to create index.list to jar first and then add certificate to it. Still I get the same error.

I have also seen that 'Trusted-Library' kind of things to be added in MF file. But this is going to be a security vulnerable.

Any help guys...

Comment: Have you tried `Trusted-Only: true` attribute? this attribute will take care of your security concerns.